# How to change dynamically Laravel form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, laravel

I am making an web app on TV series. I would like to make a form to search series with different criteria like name, creator, genre...

I want to change dynamically the second input. If I want to search series by name, the input is textfield. If I want search by genre the second input is checkbox.

My code :

```
        <!-- Ouverture du formulaire de recherche de série -->
        {!! Form::open() !!}

        <!-- Choix du type de recherche de série -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <center>{!! Form::label('Type de recherche') !!}</center>
            {!! Form::select('recherche', ['N' => 'Recherche par nom',
                                           'G' => 'Recherche par genre',
                                           'R' => 'Recherche par réalisateur'],
            'G', ['class' => 'recherche select']); !!}
        </div>

        <!-- Champs de saisie du nom de la série recherchée -->
        <div class="form-group nom">
            <center>{!! Form::label('Nom de la série recherchée') !!}</center>
            {!! Form::text('nom', null, array('required', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Nom de la série')) !!}
        </div>

        <!-- Liste des checkboxs pour la recherche de séries par genre -->
        <div class="form-group genre">
            <center>{!! Form::label('Nom du genre recherché') !!}</center>
            Action{!! Form::checkbox('action', 'action') !!}
            Western{!! Form::checkbox('western', 'western') !!}
        </div>

        <!-- Liste des checkboxs pour la recherche de séries par réalisateur -->
        <div class="form-group realisateur">
            <center>{!! Form::label('Nom du réalisateur recherché') !!}</center>
            Spielberg{!! Form::checkbox('Spielberg', 'Speilberg') !!}
            Hanks{!! Form::checkbox('Hanks', 'Hanks') !!}
        </div>

        <!-- Bouton d'envoi du formulaire de recherche de série -->
        {!! Form::submit('Rechercher', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
        <!-- Fermeture du formulaire de recherche de série -->
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This JS code doesn't change second input dynamically.

```
if($('.recherche').val() != 'N'){
    $('.nom').hide();
}
if($('.recherche').val() != 'G'){
    $('.genre').hide();
}
if($('.recherche').val() != 'R'){
    $('.realisateur').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind everything in the change event:

```
    $( ".recherche" ).change(function() {
  .....
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, When i come on the page the 3 input was visible and when i change the search's option, all 3 input was hide

Comment: That's because you need to show the other two in every if, for example: if($('.recherche').val() != 'N'){
    $('.nom').hide(); $('.genre').show(); $('.realisateur').show();
}